# Redirect traffic to another local machine requesting for a certain webpage

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, redirect, windows-server-2012, traffic

I need to redirect traffic, which is requesting for specified address(www.vlp.ee), to an another machine(10.251.36.5) located on my local network. The machine that handles the incoming traffic is linux based and running an apache server. The machine that has the homepage running, is windows based.

I have tried to make a apache 301 redirect, but that changes the value of the url address www.vlp.ee to the forwarded computer address 10.251.36.5. The server that handles the incoming traffic should listen to incoming requests, check for www.vlp.ee request and forward the requests to 10.251.36.5.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do something like this, it will listen for all requests for www.vlp.ee and in fact will serve what's hosted by your local machine 10.251.36.5.

ServerName www.vlp.ee

```
ProxyPass / http://10.251.36.5:80/
ProxyPassReverse / http://10.251.36.5:80/
<Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

You can find more info about mod_proxy : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html
Don't forget to check that the module is loaded in your apache : apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES